# Homage To Robert Johnson

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, cipher, music

*This is a revival attempt of the [Fortnightly Topic Challenge](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4614/fortnightly-topic-challenge-6-music).*

---

(Well, truthfully, I didn't know about the challenge but the puzzle I thought of this morning coincidentally is music-related so I am happily able to participate in the revival.)

> ```
> eina dbts iese rlem aioo gewb avyh lebt ftss ooea 
> tmdr dynv esyw ioer rune tlmv enra booe awsd bpdk doy 
> aoib oroo rbde somo sbkc oiev rsee csdd eial hnme 
> tkdb tibo anoo ggtp ndon ioey dwva nnyh ampr theo smb
> ```

(I have given my spell-checker a stern talking-to and believe the above is now correct.)

Comment: by the "lyrics" I think it's this one: https://youtu.be/yqVVv97pKGk?t=1m5s

Comment: The most famous song by Robert Johnson (in the title) is the Cross Road Blues. http://xroads.virginia.edu/~MUSIC/blues/crb.html

Comment: This is a song we're looking for, then?  There's not really a question here - just a bunch of encrypted letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***NOTE:- Answers are given by [DaphneB](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/12092/daphne-b) and [APrough](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14233/aprough). This wiki answer just copied their answer so that the OP could accept it. Consider upvoting their answers.***

---

> Taking the first letter of each group, going backwards, we get "standing at the crossroad babe tried to flag a ride"

And then

> Taking the second letter of each group, going forwards, we get "I believe to my soul now poor Bob is sinking down"

3rd Line

> didn't nobody seem to know me everybody pass me by.

which was gained by

> starting at 3rd character in each group (bottom left), and snaking up, then down, then up, etc.

And the 4th line

> asked the lord above have mercy now save poor bob

which is gained by

> starting at top right (ooea), and take right most character.  Shift left one group, read diagonally down to the right. go down one space, then diagonally up left.  Continue this "diagonal snaking" to get to the answer.

Answer (score 10):

Partial response:

> Taking the first letter of each group, going backwards, we get "standing at the crossroad babe tried to flag a ride"

And then

> Taking the second letter of each group, going forwards, we get "I believe to my soul now poor Bob is sinking down"

But I don't know how to use the other letters.

Comment: The Cross Road Blues exists in many different text variants. Here is a link to a version containing the second line found by you: https://drlrcs.com/i/YyL2aQoqKCRt/robert-johnson-crossroad-blues

Answer (score 9):

Working off Daphne B's work

3rd Line

> didn't nobody seem to know me everybody pass me by.

which was gained by

> starting at 3rd character in each group (bottom left), and snaking up, then down, then up, etc.

And the 4th line

> asked the lord above have mercy now save poor bob

which is gained by

> starting at top right (ooea), and take right most character.  Shift left one group, read diagonally down to the right. go down one space, then diagonally up left.  Continue this "diagonal snaking" to get to the answer.

Comment: I get it now! The meaning of it, that is.